# Is there a simple proof that representations of GL(n,k) are determined by their restriction to diagonal matrices?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.  The general linear group $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ has a subgroup $\mathrm{D}(n,k)$ consisting of invertible diagonal matrices.  These are linear algebraic groups and the inclusion is a map of linear algebraic groups.  So, we can restrict any algebraic representation of the former group to one of the latter, giving us a functor

$$ r_k \colon \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm{GL}(n,k)) \to \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm{D}(n,k)) $$

I'm trying to do this:

**Find a "simple" proof that this functor is [essentially injective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+injective+functor): i.e., if two representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ become isomorphic when restricted to $D(n,k)$, they had to be isomorphic in the first place.**

Of course different people have ideas on what counts as "simple".  By a "simple" proof I mean one that does not rely on developing the representation theory of reductive algebraic groups, or on classifying representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ using Young diagrams and Schur-Weyl duality.

I started trying to take a proof based on the theory of reductive algebraic groups and distill it to the minimum.  I got an argument that still seems a bit roundabout and unsatisfying.   It goes like this.

First consider the case of an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic zero.  Show that:

- $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ is a reductive algebraic group.
- Any finite-dimensional algebraic representation of a reductive algebraic group is determined up to isomorphism by its character.
- The semisimple elements of $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ form a Zariski dense set, so the character of any algebraic representation is determined by its restriction to the semisimple elements.  (Simple enough.)
- The character of any finite-dimensional representation is a class function, i.e. invariant under conjugation.  (Immediate.)
- When $K$ is algebraically closed, every semisimple element of $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix.  (Simple enough.)
- Thus, every finite-dimensional algebraic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ is determined up to isomorphism by the restriction of its character to $\mathrm{D}(n,K)$.   (Immediate.)
- A fortiori, every finite-dimensional algebraic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ is determined up to isomorphism by its restriction to $\mathrm{D}(n,K)$.   (Immediate.)

Then, if $k$ is of characteristic zero but not algebraically closed, let $K$ be an algebraic closure of $k$.   I get a square of functors that commutes up to natural isomorphism:

$$  \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm{GL}(n, k)) \xrightarrow{r_k} \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm D(n, k)) $$
$$ \downarrow \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \downarrow $$
$$ \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm{GL}(n, K)) \xrightarrow{r_K} \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm D(n, K)) $$

where the vertical arrows are "tensoring with $K$", i.e. $K \otimes_k -$.   The vertical arrows and the bottom arrow ($r_K$) are essentially injective.  Thus, going down and then across is essentially injective.  Thus, going across and then down is essentially injective.  But the composite of two functors can only be essentially injective if the functor you do first is essentially injective.  Thus, the top arrow ($r_k$) is essentially injective.

Most of this argument seems "simple enough" to me, but I'm not happy with these steps:

- $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ is a reductive algebraic group.
- Any finite-dimensional algebraic representation of a reductive algebraic group is determined up to isomorphism by its character.

because we are proving a fact for general reductive algebraic groups that might be easier to prove for $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$.   So, one solution to my problem would be to solve this problem:

**Find a "simple" proof that any finite-dimensional algebraic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ is determined up to isomorphism by its character.**

But there might be some other way.

Comment: Three possible angles of attack, none of which I am sure I could complete: (1) Are you willing to assume that the representations of $\operatorname{GL}(n, k)$ are semisimple? (2) Are you willing to use that $k[G]^G$ is spanned by the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, for $G = \operatorname{GL}(n, k)$? (3) Are you willing to use Lie-group machinery, e.g., by piecing $k$ together from subfields that embed in $\mathbb C$, and then doing a computation with representations of the Lie group $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb C)$?

Comment: @LSpice About (1): most likely yes: Such a result still implies that representations of GL$_n$ are semisimple (taking for granted that those of $D_n$ are, which is much easier). Because start from a rep and consider its "semisimple shadow" (i.e. keep the diagonal blocks in a triangular decomposition with irreducible diagonal blocks). Then these have the same character, hence (assuming the result) are isomorphic.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466231/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-representations-of-gln-k-are-determined-by-their#comment1209571_466231), right, that's why I asked—I feared that assuming it might amount to circularity.

Comment: $\newcommand\R{\mathsf{Rep}}\newcommand\H[2]{\operatorname{#1}(n,#2)}\newcommand\G{\H{GL}}$Why is it clear that the vertical arrow $\R(\G k) \to \R(\G K)$ is essentially surjective? \\ Incidentally, if you'd like the diagram, you can `\require{AMScd}` and then $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} \R(\G k) @>r_k>> \R(\H D k) \\ @VVV @VVV \\ \R(\G K) @>r_K>> \R(\H D K).\end{CD}$$ `\begin{CD} \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm{GL}(n, k)) @>r_k>> \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm D(n, k)) \\ @VVV @VVV \\ \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm{GL}(n, K)) @>r_K>> \mathsf{Rep}(\mathrm D(n, K)). \end{CD}`.

Comment: @LSpice: Since we’re working over characteristic 0, isn’t the fact that the representations are semisimple completely equivalent to representations being determined by their character?  This is true for any group I think since in general by Wedderburn the character of a representation determines its semisimplification.

Comment: @AndyPutman, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1209604), that certainly it follows if one knows the $\mathbb Z$-linear independence of irreducible characters.  I am not sure how easy that is if one doesn't already know that the irreducible representations are determined by their highest weights.  (Maybe that's a consequence of Wedderburn; to be honest, I don't usually think of it.)  Anyway, I don't mean to dictate what could or should be assumed, just was curious what kind of line of attack would be acceptable.

Comment: @LSpice - Alas, I don't know a "simple" proof that tensoring with K gives an essentially surjective functor Rep(GL(n,k))→ Rep(GL(n,K)); this follows from the classification of representations of GL(n,k) but that is exactly the sort of thing I'd hope to avoid here.  So yes, you've pinpointed another difficulty.  (Ideally there'd be a proof of my main result that would not even bring in the algebraic closure K.)

Comment: @LSpice wrote "Are you willing to use Lie-group machinery?"  I have a proof for K = C that I consider tolerable: it reduces the problem to U(n) and uses the theory of characters on compact groups.  So if someone can get the result for a general field of characteristic zero from the case of C in a nice way, I'd like to see that!  I could try to go down from C to Q and then back up to k, but I'm afraid I may wind up wanting to use things about Rep(GL(n,Q))→ Rep(GL(n,k)) that I only know thanks to the detailed classification of representations via weights or Young diagrams.

Comment: @LSpice: What I'm thinking about does not need the independence of irreducible characters. It actually has nothing to do with algebraic groups. Let $G$ be an arbitrary (abstract) group and let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. I claim that finite-dimensional $k$-representations of $G$ are determined by their characters if and only if finite-dimensional $k$-representations of $G$ are semisimple. The $\Rightarrow$ implication is in YCor's comment, so I just have to prove the $\Leftarrow$ implication.  So (continued)

Comment: (continued) assume that finite-dimensional $k$-representations of $G$ are semisimple and let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional $k$-representations with the same character.  By Theorem 7.19 in Lam's book "A first course in non-commutative rings" (a consequence of Wedderburn's theorem), the Jordan-Holder factors of $V$ and $W$ are the same. But since they're semisimple, $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic to the direct sums of their Jordan-Holder factors, so they're isomorphic.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1209622), I apologise for my inadvertent use of ‘surjective’ in place of ‘injective’, which you were too polite to correct. If we grant essential injectivity, one can observe that any two polynomial representations over $k$ are both defined over a finitely generated extension $k'$ of $\mathbb Q$, which may be embedded in $\mathbb C$; and then the equivalence over $\mathbb C$ would imply that over $k'$, hence over $k$ (as you suggest, but with a slightly larger base field). I am trying to see if a generic-element argument can avoid the assumption.

Comment: Btw, I believe tensoring with K over k gives a functor Rep(GL(n,k))→ Rep(GL(n,K)) that's both ess. inj. and ess. surj., and these days I've been using three lemmas a lot in my work: 1) the composite of ess. inj. functors is ess. inj., 2) if the composite of two functors is ess. inj. then the first functor you apply must be ess. inj., 3) if the composite of two functors is ess. inj. and the first functor you apply is ess. surj. then the second must be ess. inj.

Comment: One reason I'm interested in essentially injective functors is that essentially injective functors between semisimple categories induce injections on their Grothendieck groups, and its one of a trio of properties of a functor that Todd Trimble suggested as a reasonable "categorification" of the concept of "injection on Grothendieck groups".

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466231/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-representations-of-gln-k-are-determined-by-their#comment1209776_466231), yes, that is true, essentially because the result you cite here is true, and the analogous statement holds for $\operatorname D(n, k)$.

Comment: @AndyPutman - I like your proof that finite-dimensional k-representations of any group are determined by their characters if all such reps are semisimple - thanks!  I see how this result can be reduced to Lam's result on modules of k-algebras.  But I'm dealing with algebraic representations of a linear algebraic group, and these are comodules of a coalgebra, not modules of an algebra.  Is it possible, or even easy, to adapt the proof?

Comment: @JohnBaez: There is no need to work with coalgebras.  These are still representations of the abstract group of k-points of your algebraic group, so Lam’s theorem applies (it has no eg cardinality hypotheses, and a class function is still just a class function!).  The only addendum is that you are not working with all representations, but just the (continued)

Comment: subcategory of algebraic representations.  But the argument I gave works verbatim if you only know a subcategory of representations are semisimple — what you learn is that representations in that category are determined by their characters as elements of that category (there might be non-algebraic ones that are not semisimple and have the same character as algebraic ones).

Comment: @AndyPutman there's something you're using here, because over finite fields, restricting to the $k$-points does not know the original representation. So you're probably using that $k$-points in $\operatorname{GL}_n$ are (Zariski) dense if $k$ is infinite, since $\operatorname{GL}_n$ is rational. Anyhoo, it seems fine in the end.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: That’s right!  I probably should have made that explicit.

Comment: Does this count? Let $G$ be an algebraic group over a subfield $k$ of $\mathbb{C}$. If (a) $G(k)$ is Zariski dense in $G$, and (b) the finite-dimensional representations of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ are semisimple, then the representations of $G$ are determined up to isomorphism by their characters. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional representation of $G$, and let $A$ be the $k$-subalgebra of $End_{k}(V)$ generated by the $g\in G(k)$. Then $A$ is semisimple because $A_{\mathbb{C}}$ is, and so the representation of $A$ on $V$ is determined by its character (Wedderburn theory).

Comment: Better, given two finite-dimensional representations $V$ and $W$ of $G$ with the same character, apply the argument with $A$ the $k$-subalgebra of $End(V⊕W)$ generated by the $g\in G(k)$. Instead of $A$, you can use the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra of $G$ (and apply Bourbaki Algebre, VIII, 13.4).

Comment: Short answer is no: there is no simple proof that the finite-dimensional representations of $GL(n)$ are determined up to isomorphism by their characters. As noted, this immediately implies the representations are semisimple, but over $\mathbb{C}$, this was not proved for SU(n) until 1924 (by Schur using compactness), and deduced for SL(n) by Weyl (1925) with his well-known (nonsimple?) argument. It is possible to prove semisimplicity for the Lie algebra of SL(n) algebraically, and deduce it for SL(n), but I wouldn't call this proof simple. As I noted, it suffices to do this over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @anon - I'm content with, or at least quite resigned to, the usual proof for $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ that takes Weyl's detour through the compact form $\mathrm{U}(n)$ using the fact that every element of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ is diagonalizable.   You seem to be leveraging this to get the result for subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ - is that accurate?  What about other fields of characteristic zero?

Comment: It obviously suffices to show semisimplicity over a finitely generated subfield of your field, which can then be embedded in $\mathbb{C}$. Certainly, it is well-known that semisimplicity over $\mathbb{C}$ implies it over any subfield. The proof I prefer uses the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra and Bourbaki Algebre, VIII, 13.4.